# How generated values work for Entity Framework Core (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

I am using `EF Core 3.1` with `SQL Server` provider. If not specified otherwise `EF Core` uses generated values for entity keys. (The key is being generated by the provider, in this case `SQL Server`) In following documentation [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#value-generation-patterns) I found statement that:

> For example, when using SQL Server, values will be automatically
>   generated for GUID properties (using the SQL Server sequential GUID
>   algorithm)

I was using `SQL Profiler` to investigate EF core generated queries and I noticed that for adding an entity it generated following `SQL`:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [MySchema].[MyTable] ([Id],  ...)
VALUES (@p0, ...);
',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier, ...',@p0='B3DC06A3-2B58-46A0-9085-7A17B064433F', ...
```

here I see that query already has `GUID` in the query, meaning that it obtains it before generating the query. But I have't noticed any attidional calls in `SQL Profiler`.

How does the generated values work behind the hood?

Comment: Try setting the log level for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` on debug. You'll see all the sql queries on your logs so, no need for SQL Profiler

Answer (score 0):

So I misinterpreted the documentation. It doesn't actually use SQL Server to get the `Guid` value, but copied the algorithm itself and creates the `Guid` on server side. Which makes sense as you are saving a round trip.

You can find the algorithm [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/master/src/EFCore/ValueGeneration/SequentialGuidValueGenerator.cs).